# Magento 2 - Dimensional Weight Confusion

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods

I am having a very difficult time finding some clear answers on using dimensional weight in Magento 2. Dimensional weight is generally an option with different shipping providers but all of the articles I have found online imply that dimensional weight is just default in Magento 2 when using a major shipping provider. Every article also sounds like it has just been optimized for SEO but are not actually useful because they don't fully make sense. Here are several examples:

https://bsscommerce.com/blog/how-to-set-up-shipping-methods-in-magento-2-part-2/

```
Four main carriers supported in Magento 2 Dimensional Weight shipping 
method includes:

...

Although the configuration of each carrier may differ, all shipping 
service providers require you to have a shipping account which provides 
you with essential information like user ID, gateway URL to complete 
the setup of each shipping method.

Because these 4 shipping methods share some major similarities, I will 
only focus on the configuration of United Parcel Service.
```

The article goes on to not mention how to actually enable or configure dimensional weight. Other similar articles:

https://www.mconnectmedia.com/blog/magento-2-dimensional-weight-shipping-method-part-4/

https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-configure-magento-2-shipping-methods

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-shipping-methods-tuts/#4magento_2_dimensional_weight

---

There is a guide for Dimensional Weight from Magento directly but it is for 1.9.x and states that it is not supported and you need to use a third party service/module (http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/shipping/weight-dimensional.html).

---

Let's assume that is supported (even though I have not seen hard evidence of it), how could dimensional weight be supported with dimensions being part of the Magento product set up. We could set custom attributes to products but width, length and height would need to be present for a true dimensional weight to be calculated.

I'm basically just looking for a hard yes or no and to be pointed in the direction of a solution if there is one.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @zack6849 No. There doesn't seem to be any definitive answers on this that I've found yet. I'm keeping my eye out and hopefully if an answer arises, someone will update this...

Comment: I've noticed that ShipStation offers a REST API that can in fact do rates based on dimensions, we're investigating that, i've also asked them if they're planning on building out their own shipping method to advertise their rates, so maybe they'll pick up on that and it'll be an official functionality from then

Comment: Did you find any answers to this yet? The whole internet is filled with SEO optimized articles exactly like what you said. Nothing useful. The official docs recommend that we use Magneto Shipping. Not sure how that will help. https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/weight-dimensional.html. 
**shipperhq** provides extensions seem very useful. But pricy for me to sign up with their monthly subscription.

Answer (score 1):

I am also having a very difficult time understanding this but as far as I am aware of, there is NO actual support of dimensional weight on as of Magento 2.2.6. Although they have added the default Length, Width, and High but it is probably for Magento's own shipping called Mangento Shipping and unfortunately it does come with a high monthly subscription, just like the only promising third party extension called "ShipperHQ" and thus I was not able to test them.

I have researched so many extensions in hope of finding ones that would provide accurate live rate with dimensional weight included in the calculation but there is just simply none. As for a store that charges shipping, it is very difficult to provide an accurate shipping estimate for customer.

While some have suggested to put the calculated dimensional weight as the "weight" in the backend, while it will somewhat works but it is not ideal and honestly not a long term solution.

Comment: So to be clear, the new added attributes into products (Width, Height, Length) have nothing to do with shipping and volumetric calculation? Because all of sudden after the update there are these dimensional new attributes and I do not feel comfortable using them yet because I do not understand them. Are they related to the actual product, the product box, or the product after packaging?

Comment: These new attributes can definitely be used for calculating shipping and such, however, as I mention, without a subscription to their service (Magento Shipping), these attributes does not play a role in other purposes. I would assume these attributes are to be used for calculation shipping so might be best to set as your shipping dimensions.

Comment: Were any of you guys able to find a clear answer re: dimensional weight in Magento 2.3+? Magento Shipping seems like overkill, but trying to find other ways to take advantage of the new dimension fields.

Comment: @brackfost We went with a third party extension to use the dimension shipping. https://www.infomodus.com/fedex-shipping-manager-for-magento-2/     however, it cost $350 for the two extension that requires for this to work, and it only works with one carrier, additional carriers would require another purchase for that carrier. It is by far the most capable solution we have came across that doesn't require a monthly charge.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry ! Taking a look at this extension. Did you check out https://amasty.com/magento-2-dimensional-shipping-weight.html ? If so, curious what the hurdle was there.

Comment: @brackfost This Amasty's extension came across my list too, but in my application, I needed live rate from FedEx and Amasty's extension seem like I will have to setup some table rates (which I don't want). So eventually I went with the one I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

IN UPS Worldship, create a sample shipment using the dimensions of a common box size you normally pack. Fill in all the requested info, including a minimal weight and the dimensions. Hit tab after entering the weight, and it will show you something like "Dimensional weight 20x12x4 8 pounds applied." This tells you that a 20x12x4 box will be charged for 8 pounds, even if only 5 pounds of product is in the box. Knowing this, you can get the basic applied weights for each box size that you use, and set that weight for the product. For example, a keyboard would ship in a 20x12x4 box, but it only weighs 4 pounds. To avoid being overcharged by the carrier, set the weight as 8 pounds in your catalog.